# Efficient counting

Tags: code-golf, number

When I was a kid, and wanted to count the dollar bills in my life savings, I would count out loud:

> one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;
>   eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty;
>   twenty-one, twenty-two, twenty-three, twenty-four, twenty-five...

Eventually I got tired of pronouncing each of these multi-syllable numbers. Being mathematically minded, I created a much more efficient method of counting:

> one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;
>   one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, twenty;
>   one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, thirty...

As you can see, I would only pronounce the digit(s) that have changed from the previous number. This has the added advantage that it's considerably more repetitive than the English names for numbers, and therefore requires less brainpower to compute.

### Challenge

Write a program/function which takes in a positive integer and outputs/returns how I would count it: that is, the right-most non-zero digit and all trailing zeroes.

#### Examples

```
   1    1
   2    2
  10   10
  11    1
  29    9
  30   30
  99    9
 100  100
 119    9
 120   20
 200  200
 409    9
1020   20
```

A full list of test-cases shouldn't be necessary. This is [A274206](http://oeis.org/A274206) on OEIS.

### Rules

- Your entry must theoretically work for all positive integers, ignoring precision and memory issues.
- Input and output must be in decimal.
- You may choose to take input and/or output as a number, a string, or an array of digits.
- Input is guaranteed to be a positive integer. Your entry can do anything for invalid input.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: So does "in decimal" include a list of decimal digits, like `[1,0,2,0]` -> `[2,0]` for the last test case? (I'm unclear on the phrase "single-item array").

Comment: @JonathanAllan By "single-item array" I meant an array that contains a single number or string which represents the integer. I didn't think allowing arrays of digits was a good idea, but now it kind of seems like an arbitrary restriction since strings are allowed (and strings are very similar to arrays in many languages). So I'll allow an array of digits unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Dang it, you stole my secret :P

Comment: I think almost everyone counted like this as a kid. ;) At least I did as well. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen "as a kid"?

Comment: @MartinEnder Hehe, ok, maybe everyone still counts like this. ^_^

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n%10or 10*f(n/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcexCoAgEADQub7iltDioDubFPqSajBCEOoKcfDvzenxalhv/5yXB3EyML0JmKagZWYaa2gtEAU2RoNMyE2LC6G1re2G0BAdru@@FCVDQbVnhRB0GesP)

A recursive formula works out very cleanly. If the last digit is nonzero, output it. Otherwise, remove the final zero, compute the output for that, and multiply it by 10.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-3 bytes by having I/O as a [decimal list of digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110836/efficient-counting/110861#comment269927_110836).

```
ṫTṪ
```

Test suite at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w5@qQhztX/dc53O7Ndbj9UdOayP//o6MNY3WijYDYUMcATIL5OpZA0hgsYglmA2Vh8lC@EZhvBBU3AdIwdSCZWAA)**

#### How?

```
ṫTṪ - Main link: listOfDigits  e.g.  [1,    0,    2,    0]  or [1,      1,    9  ]
 T  - truthy indexes                 [1,          3      ]     [1,      2,    3  ]
ṫ   - tail (vectorises)              [[1,0,2,0],  [2,0]  ]     [[1,1,9],[1,9],[9]]
  Ṫ - tail pop                                    [2,0]                       [9]
```

---

If we could not take decimal lists a 6 byter is:

```
DµṫTṪḌ
```

Which you can see **[here](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9yaOvDnatDHu5c9XBHz/@jew63P2pa4/7/f7ShjpGOoYGOIZC21DE20LG0BHJBfCBtZKBjBGSbGIDEjAxiAQ)**.

This does the same thing, but converts an integer to a decimal list beforehand and converts back to an integer afterwards.

Comment: As I was scrolling past the first few answers, I said to myself, "I bet there's a 3-byte Jelly solution..."

Answer (score 9):

## C, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Proud of this as I abuse two C exploits to golf this up (described at end of post); This is specifically for C (GCC)

---

3) `b=10;f(a){a=a%b?:b*f(a/b);}`//27 bytes

2) <s>`b;f(a){b=a=a%10?:10*f(a/10);}`</s> //29 bytes

1) <s>`f(i){return i%10?:10*f(i/10);}`</s> //30 bytes

[Try it online (27 byte version)](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59ka2hgnaaRqFmdaJuommRvlaQF5OknaVrX/s/MK1HITczM09Cs5lJQKCgC8tM0lFQzY/KUdNI0jDU1rbEIm2EXNjTAIW6ESxyXBgPcMgZQmaLUktKiPAUDa67a/1/z8nWTE5MzUgE)

---

First attempt (30 bytes): Abuses the fact that in GCC if no value is declared in ternary, the conditional value will be returned. Hence why my ternary operator is blank for the truth return value.

Second attempt (29 bytes): Abuses **memory bug** in GCC where, as far as I understand, if a function has no return value, when more than two variables have been meaningfully utilized in the function, the last set value of the first argument variable will be returned.
   *(Edit: but this "set value" must set in certain ways, for example setting a variable with `=` or `+=` works but setting it with `%=` does not work; weird)*

Third attempt (27 bytes): Since I must meaningfully utilize the second variable (b) anyways to properly abuse the memory bug mentioned above, I may as well use it as an actual variable for "10" for substitution. 
   *(Note: I should be able to swap `a=a%b` with `a%=b` to save another byte but unfortunately this causes the memory bug exploit above to stop "working", so I can't)*

Comment: You might want to add "GCC" to the title of your answer since it's GCC-specific (it doesn't work on clang). Also, the "memory bug" is probably just undefined behavior that happens to work due to the specific stack frame layout that GCC uses. It probably doesn't work on other platforms, even with GCC.

Comment: @gurka Done, thanks

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
!`.0*$
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VI4PqvmKBnoKXy/78hlxGXoQGXIZC25DI24LK0BHJBfCBtZMBlBGSbGIDEDA0A) (all test cases)

Output matches of a digit followed by any zeros at the end of the input string. Though not required, this also happens to work for `0`.

Comment: Huh, I had figured `[1-9]` (or `[^0]`) would be necessary instead of `\d`. I guess the greediness of `*` ensures the correct output every time.

Comment: @ETHproductions This has nothing to do with the greediness of `*` but with the fact that matches are searched for from left to right. `\d0*?$` would also work.

Comment: using the regex `.0*$` should work

Comment: If there's a (short enough) way to output only the last match, you could use `.0*`

Comment: @12Me21 The only way to do that is to only match the last occurrence, or to use a replace or something. It won't be shorter.

Comment: @12Me21 specifically, you'd need `-1=` in front of the `\``.

Answer (score 7):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 18 <s>32</s> bytes

<s>I think I'll have to spend sometime on this later and see if I can compress it a bit.  But for the moment here it is.</s>
Turns out I was thinking about this totally the wrong way. Now the process incrementally applies a mod (1,10,100,1000,...) to the input integer and prints out the first one which isn't zero.  Bit more boring, but shorter.

```
!N%*I1^\.u;u@O\;;r
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=IU4lKkkxXlwudTt1QE9cOzty&input=MTAyMjAxMA==&speed=20)

```
    ! N
    % *
I 1 ^ \ . u ; u
@ O \ ; ; r . .
    . .
    . .
```

Comment: Always nice to see a Cubix answer :)

Comment: @obarakon Got an improved one to put up soon.  Really did this one the wrong way

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript <s>19</s> 18 bytes

Thanks to ETHproductions for golfing off one byte and Patrick Roberts for golfing off two bytes

```
x=>x.match`.0*$`
```

Returns an array of strings that match the regex of being at the end of the input string with any character followed by the largest possible number of zeroes.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9X2FrV6GXm1iSnKGhr2egpaKfrvm/uKTINjqWqzwjMydVA8jRy0nNSy/JsLE00ATxCkqLMzSUlLSRpLQNDTU1uZLz84rzc1L1cvLTwXK5iQUaaZp6WfmZeRrqCuqamv8B)

Comment: I don't think you need the `g`, as there's only ever one match to find.

Comment: Save 2 bytes by using ``x=>x.match`.0*$` ``

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, 21 bytes

```js
f=n=>n%10||10*f(n/10)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>n%10||10*f(n/10)

console.log(f(1   )); //  1
console.log(f(2   )); //  2
console.log(f(10  )); //  10
console.log(f(29  )); //  9
console.log(f(99  )); //  9
console.log(f(1020)); //  20
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
a₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wP/FRU@P//9GGOkY6hgY6hkDaUsfYQMfSEsgF8YG0kYGOEZBtYgASMzKIBQA)

The suffix builtin `a₁`, for integers, is implemented as:

```prolog
brachylog_adfix('integer':1, 'integer':0, 'integer':0).
brachylog_adfix('integer':1, 'integer':I, 'integer':P) :-
    H #\= 0,
    H2 #\= 0,
    abs(P) #=< abs(I),
    integer_value('integer':Sign:[H|T], I),
    integer_value('integer':Sign:[H2|T2], P),
    brachylog_adfix('integer':1, [H|T], [H2|T2]).
```

Brachylog likes to be able to treat integers as lists of digits, and for that it uses the custom utility predicate `integer_value/2`. The interesting thing about `integer_value/2` here is that since it has to be able to correctly translate a digit list with leading zeros, it ends up also being able to translate an integer to a digit list with leading zeros, so predicates that don't want that to happen (most of them, *especially* the nondet ones like `a`) forbid the heads of their digit lists from being 0. So, while `a₁` generates suffixes shortest first for lists and strings, it skips over any suffix of an integer with a leading 0, which in addition to removing duplicates, also means that the first suffix generated is the rightmost non-zero digit with all trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, 12

```
grep -o .0*$
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@59elFqgoJuvoGegpfL/vyGXEZehAZchkLbkMjbgsrQEckF8IG1kwGUEZJsYgMSMDAA).

Answer (score 3):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 5 bytes

```
d\0*e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#@58SY6CV@v@/oYGBkQEA)

### Explanation

```
       Find the longest substring of the input matching this pattern:
d      a digit, then
 \0*   zero or more 0s, then
    e  edge of input (which is handled as an Nx1 rectangle of characters).
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 74 bytes

```
{({}<>)<>}(()){{}<>(({}<>)[((((()()()){}){}){}){}]<(())>){((<{}{}>))}{}}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PYrBCQAxEALb0Ucg3HvZRsK9rgyx9k2Wg@ggKJYgRzLSAKku@KeFFtuUL2/0MSkgZDnJk4eqZ84a3wY)

Only prints the last non-0 and all trailing 0s.

**Explanation:**

```
{({}<>)<>}                    # Move everything to the other stack (reverse the input)
(())                          # Push a 1 to get started
{                             # do...
  {}<>                        #   pop the result of the equals check (or initial 1)
  (                           #   push...
    ({}<>)                    #     the top value from the other stack (also put this on the stack)
    [((((()()()){}){}){}){}]  #     minus the ASCII value of 0
    <(())>                    #     on top of a 1
  )                           #   close the push   
  {                           #   if not zero (ie. if not equal)
    ((<{}{}>))                #     replace the 1 from 3 lines back with a 0
  }{}                         #   end if and pop the extra 0
}                             # while the copied value != "0"
{}                            # pop the result of the equals check
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 19 bytes

Two versions, both 19 bytes:

```
:s/\v.*([^0]0*)/\1
:s/.*\([^0]0*\)/\1
```

Plus a trailing carriage return on each.

[Verify all test-cases online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2@lWqyvpxWjER1nEGugFaOpH2P4/78hlxGXoQGXIZC25DI24LK0BHJBfCBtZMBlBGSbGIDEjAwA) (One byte added to test on multiple lines)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 18 bytes

```
If fPart(.1Ans
Return
Ans.1
prgmA
10Ans
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 33 bytes

Implemented as an unnamed function

```
function(x)rle(x%%10^(0:99))$v[2]
```

This applies a mod of 10^0 through 10^99.  `rle` is used to reduce the results down so that the second item is always the result we want.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#S7PlSivNSy7JzM/TqNAsyknVqFBVNTSI0zCwsrTU1FQpizaK/V9elFmSqlGcWFCQU6lRnFqoYaRjaGBgoGOkqZOmqaOurmNqoPn/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```sh
<<<${(M)1%[^0]*}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPlVqWmKNQnFqioKuroAIS/W9jY6NSreGraagaHWcQq1X7PyUfKGrIZcRlzGXCZWjAZWwAxEYGXCYGYAwigDwA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPlVqWmKNQnFqioKuroAIS/W9jY6NSreGraagaHWcQq1X7PyUfKGrIZcRlzGXCZWjAZWwAxEYGXCYGYAwigDwA)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>25</s> 20 bytes

***-5 bytes** by @roblogic*

```bash
echo ${1#${1%[^0]*}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopCTmZdqrZCSz5ValpijUJxaoqCrq6ACEv2fmpyRr6BSbagMxKrRcQaxWrW1/1PygTKGXEZcxlwmXIYGXMYGQGxkwGViAMYgAsgDAA)
<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopCTmZdqrZCSz5ValpijUJxaoqCrq6ACEv1fZKtSbagaHWcQq1XLlZqcka8A5CurFNX@T8kHShtyGXEZc5lwGRpwGRsAsZEBl4kBGIMIIA8A)</s>

---
Shells need to call external programs to use regex, so we have to make do with globbing.

The `${1%[^0]*}` expansion matches the shortest suffix beginning with a nonzero character, and removes it.

- In Zsh, adding the `(M)` flag causes the matched suffix to be kept instead of removed.
- In Bash, the `${1%  }` expansion removes as a prefix whatever is left.

Comment: 20 bytes in bash: `echo ${1#${1%[^0]*}}`

Answer (score 1):

### [GNU sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), <s>17</s> 14 + 1(r flag) = 15 bytes

**Edit:** 2 bytes less thanks to [Riley](/users/57100/riley)

```sed
s:.*([^0]):\1:
```

It works by deleting everything until the right-most nonzero digit, which is then printed along with any existing trailing zeros. The script can handle multiple tests in one run, each on a separate line.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#K05NUdAtUlD/X2ylp6URHWcQq2kVY2j1X/2/IZcRl6EBlyGQtuQyNuCytARyQXwgbWTAZQRkmxiAxIwMAA) (all test examples)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to [@B. Mehta!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64748/b-mehta)*

```
tfX>Jh)
```

Input and output are an array of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@SFmHnlaH5/3@0oY6BjpGOQSwA)

Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hfkhZh55Wh@d8l5H@0YSxXtBEQGyoYgEkwX8ESSBqDRSzBbKAsTB7KNwLzjaDiJkAaIg5kgKQA).

#### Explanation

```
t     % Input string implicitly. Duplicate
f     % Push indices of non-zero digits
X>    % Keep maximum, say k
Jh    % Attach 1j to give [k, 1j]. This is interpreted as an index "k:end"
)     % Index into original string. Display implcitly
```

Comment: Since we're allowed to take input and output as a vector of integers, you can remove the `48-` entirely, saving 3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@SFmHnlaH5/3@0oY6BjpGOQSwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 26 bytes

Pure function which takes a list of digits and outputs a list of digits:

```
#/.{___,x_,y:0...}:>{x,y}&
```

### Explanation

```
#                           First argument
 /.                           Replace
   {                              start of list followed by
    ___,                          zero or more elements followed by
        x_,                       an element (referred to later as x) followed by
           y:0...                 a sequence of zero or more 0s (referred to later as y) followed by
                 }                end of list
                  :>            with
                    {x,y}         {x,y}
                         &   End of function.
```

This works since it finds the leftmost match for `x`, which must be the rightmost nonzero element of the list since it is followed by a sequence of zero of more `0`s and then the end of  the list.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 47 bytes

this is a lambda expression assignable to a `IntUnaryOperator`:

```
x->{int m=1;for(;x%m<1;m*=10);return x%m*m/10;}
```

explanation:
multiply m by 10 until `x%m` is not 0.
`return x%m*m/10` requires the division because m is an order of magnitude more than the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 10 bytes

```perl6
{+m/.0*$/}
```

Trivial regex solution. Inputs and outputs a number.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

Based on [this JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110872/65012), so I suppose all the credits kinda go to him.

### Golfed

```
i=a=>a%10<1?10*i(a/10):a%10;
```

- -2 bytes by removing `()` around `a` thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

Comment: I think you need to explicitly name the function `i` for this to work as you're using recursion.

Comment: @Emigna you're right! I totally missed that :(

Comment: Updated it but I'm not 100% sure if it's correct this way

Comment: I don't know the consensus on this in C#. That syntax is valid, but will only work if the delegate has already been declared (otherwise `i` will be undeclared for the recursive call).

Comment: The parenthesis around `a` is not required either way though.

Comment: @Emigna Really? I'm just new to using lambdas/anonymous functions so I'm not sure yet haha, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
RD0Ê1k>£R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/kYnC4yzDb7tDioP//ow11DHSMdAxiAQ)
or as a 
[Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymrDP4f5GJwuMsw2@7Q4qD/lUqH91spHN6vpPPfkMuIy9CAyxBIW3IZG3BZWgK5ID6QNjLgMgKyTQxAYkYGAA)

**Explanation**

```
R          # reverse input
 D         # duplicate
  0Ê       # check each for inequality with 0
    1k     # get the index of the first 1
      >    # increment
       £   # take that many digits from the input
        R  # reverse
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0BIXg8DMmP//jY1MjQwB "05AB1E – Try It Online") - 6 bytes

Comment: Or 5 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9oYODm9//QEpf4zJj/tba1/42NTI0MAQ "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: That's only checking the last digit. It should be the last non-zero digit and all after.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 27 bytes

```
10&|`(10*(p%&10))@.(0=10&|)
```

It's based off of xnor's formula, so credits to him.

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 49 bytes

lambda, assignable to `(List<Int>) -> List<Int>`

```
{a->a.slice(a.indexOfLast{it in 1..9}..a.size-1)}
```

- implicit parameter name `it` in `indexOfLast`
- `..` for building ranges

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 12 bytes

11, plus 1 for `-nE` instead of `-e`

```
say/(.0*$)/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
f".0*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P01Jz0BL5f9/JUMDIwMlAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
æΩ$3╚
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=91ea2433c8&i=1%0A2%0A10%0A11%0A30%0A99%0A100%0A409%0A1020%0A&a=1&m=2)

#### Procedure:

1. Calculate "multiplicity" by 10.  (That's the number of times 10 evenly divides the input)
2. Add 1.
3. Keep that many characters from the right of (the input as a string).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĀÅ¡θ
```

I/O as a list of digits.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SMPh1kMLz@34/z/aUsdAxxiITYDYIBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvxPmobRKnkn2lS/D/Iw2HWw8tPLfjv5fOf0MuIy5DAy5DIG3JZWzAZWkJ5IL4QNrIgMsIyDYxAIkBOZYGxgYmBgYA) (test suite contains a join for better readability).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ā     # Python-style truthify each digit in the (implicit) input-list (0 if 0; 1 if [1-9])
      #  i.e. [9,0,4,0,3,0,0] → [1,0,1,0,1,0,0]
 Å¡   # Split the (implicit) input-list on truthy values (1s)
      #  i.e. [9,0,4,0,3,0,0] and [1,0,1,0,1,0,0] → [[],[9,0],[4,0],[3,0,0]]
   θ  # And only leave the last inner list
      #  i.e. [[],[9,0],[4,0],[3,0,0]] → [3,0,0]
      # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
V€ỵ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVYlRTIlODIlQUMlRTElQkIlQjUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDMCUyQzIlMkMwJmZsYWdzPXQ=)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
V€ỵ  # Implicit input
V    # Truthy indices
 €ỵ  # Head remove over each
     # Take the last item
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 62 bytes

Input (variable `A`) and output (variable `B`) are both arrays of digits. Run the ticker to start the program.

**Ticker:**

```
B->join(A[n],B),n->\left\{A[n]=0:n-1,0\right\}
```

**Expression List:**

```
B=[]
n=A.length
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yberrez2td)

Scans `A` from right to left until a nonzero digit is encountered. Afterwards, set `n=0` to invalidate the action and halt the program.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a7eggt0cn9?nographpaper)

Comment: BTW welcome to Code Golf! I don't see Desmos answers often from people other than me, so it's always exciting to see other people golfing in Desmos!

Comment: That being said, if you would like to learn more about various Desmos golfing tips, please check out the [Tips for Golfing in Desmos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100/tips-for-code-golfing-in-desmos) page, or check out some of [my Desmos answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a96039%20is%3aanswer%20desmos&searchOn=3) to see some of the tricks I use. I hope you will do more Desmos golfing in the future!

Comment: @AidenChow Thanks! I started writing programs in Desmos last summer and eventually I realized that I could try golfing in Desmos after looking for something new to keep myself busy on. I just finished turning my brainfuck interpreter to plaintext so now I'll have to read those tips and optimize it again haha

Comment: Sounds cool! If you don't mind, could I take a look at your brainfuck interpreter (and the plaintext you have)? Maybe I can try helping you golf it.

Comment: [Sure thing!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e5dhhoc0n9) In terms of LaTeX, I think I've managed to cut everthing down except for the `c` action, which keeps failing when I get rid of the `\left` and `\right`s. For the syntax, on the other hand, I've done what I could but it's probably still suboptimal.

Comment: In case the golfed names are too confusing, if you look at the [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gauo0ldfek) at the top of the expressions list, you will find an annotated copy of the interpreter with names that perhaps make more sense. (I originally wrote this interpreter last week so golfing it was a bit of an afterthought)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147936/discussion-between-fwoosh-and-aiden-chow).

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 34 bytes

```
|n|n[n.rfind(|d|d!='0')?..].into()
```

If I knew a way to use impl traits on closures, I could remove 7 bytes from `.into()`, but It doesn't seem like that's allowed on `fn pointers` or `Fn` objects.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23%21%5Bfeature%28is_sorted%29%5D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+solution%3A+fn%28%26%27static+str%29+-%3E+Option%3C%26%27static+str%3E+%3D+%7Cn%7C+n%5Bn.rfind%28%7Cd%7C+d+%21%3D+%270%27%29%3F..%5D.into%28%29%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+%7Cn%7Cn%5Bn.rfind%28%7Cd%7Cd%21%3D%270%27%29%3F..%5D.into%28%29%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%221%22%29%2C+Some%28%221%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%222%22%29%2C+Some%28%222%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%2210%22%29%2C+Some%28%2210%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%2211%22%29%2C+Some%28%221%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%2229%22%29%2C+Some%28%229%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%2230%22%29%2C+Some%28%2230%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%2299%22%29%2C+Some%28%229%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%22100%22%29%2C+Some%28%22100%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%22119%22%29%2C+Some%28%229%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%22120%22%29%2C+Some%28%2220%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%22200%22%29%2C+Some%28%22200%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%22409%22%29%2C+Some%28%229%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%221020%22%29%2C+Some%28%2220%22%29%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%220%22%29%2C+None%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Ttȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJUdMivIiwiIiwiWzIsMCwwXSJd)

Port of Jelly.

### Explained

```
Ttȯ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
T    # ‎⁡Truthy indices of the input.
 t   # ‎⁢Last item of that
  ȯ  # ‎⁣input[that:]
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
}.~_1{I.@:*
```

Port of Jelly. Takes a digit list.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxulavLt6w2lPPwUoLInLTR5MrNTkjX0FHTyFNTc9OwdDayNpQwQCIgSwFS2tjINsSSAPFIKJgthGQbQQWMQGSEFkgH2LmggUQGgA)

```
}.~_1{I.@:*
      I.@:*  NB. indices of positive numbers
   _1{       NB. tail
}.~          NB. drop that many items
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
`1QY0mN%e>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%601QY0mN%25e%3E&input=1120100)

```
  QY       -     digits(input)
    0mN    -    map(^, i != 0)
 1     %   -   indecies(^, i == 1)
        e  -  ^[-1]
`        > - str(input)[^:]
```

#### 11 bytes:

```
`D\0mN1R%e>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%60D%5C0mN1R%25e%3E&input=1120100)

#### 13 bytes:

```
`D\0mN_1R@_t>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%60D%5C0mN_1R%40_t%3E&input=1120100)

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell 57 Bytes**

```
f(x:s)a|x=='0'=f s$'0':a|1>0=x:a
t x=f(reverse.show$x)[]

Input    -> Output
t 120    -> "20"
t 30200  -> "200"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 88 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set z=
:l
@if %s:~-1%==0 set z=0%z%&set s=%s:~,-1%&goto l
@echo %s:~-1%%z%
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 14 bytes

```
->n{n[/.0*$/]}
```

Input is a string (allowed by the rules)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
x!d|m<-mod x d,m>0=m|e<-10*d=x!e
(!10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@1@hmFKTa6Obm5@iUKGQopNrZ2CbW5Nqo2tooJViW6GYypVmq6FoaKD5PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFIU3B2MDIwOA/AA) Usage: `(!10) 1020` yields `20`.

**Explanation:**

`x!d` is a recursive formula which computes `x` modulo `d` with initially `d=10`. If the result is larger zero it is returned, otherwise recursively `x!(10*d)` is called.

**Other approaches:** (39 bytes)

```hs
x!d|m<-x`mod`10^d,m>0=m|e<-1+d=x!e;(!1)
f x=[y|y<-[x`mod`10^e|e<-[1..]],y>0]!!0
f x=[y|y<-map(mod x.(10^))[1..],y>0]!!0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 33 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll(".*?(.0*)$","$1")
```

I/O as a String.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVCxbsIwEN35ipPFEEOxnMASUFtVncvCCB1McCpT40TxQYVQvj2cnaSDT@/e87t39lnd1OJ8@u0Kq7yHL2XcYwJgHOqmVIWGbWgBdtgY9wNlMgDPN8S3EyoeFZoCtuDgtfOLNy8aXVvyflibMDF7T4Sc8Sl7YdOU8W4TPPX1aMkzWG@VOcGFoofp@29QvM8tq2aMRO3xU3kNa3D6D8arD5bS6IxOKkOJXU5lGdo8j0KvRJwFnEVmJXs1UrlcyhXRLY/B9OS7R30R1RVFTVFoXTKuMGcHXB@QzZ0o/0k@fEnbPQE)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                         // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.replaceAll(".*?(.0*)$", //  Replace all occurrences of this match,
               "$1")        //  with this replacement
```

*Regex explanation:*

```java
.*?(.0*)$                   // MATCH:
.*?                         //  Zero or more optional characters
                            //  (the optional is used to give other 0+ matches 
                            //   higher priority/precedence)
    .                       //  Followed by any character
     0*                     //  Followed by zero or more literal 0s
        $                   //  At the end of the string
   (   )                    //  And capture those non-optional characters in capture group 1

$1                          // REPLACEMENT:
                            //  The content of capture group 1, which basically removes
                            //  the optional characters outside the capture group
```